# Pressure force on screen detection using flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, pressure

I am searching for a function in flutter (web) that can detect the amount of pressure tap force on the screen. Any help?

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerEvent/pressure.html and/or https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ForcePressGestureRecognizer-class.html

Comment: Hello, I have used the pressure property in the PointerEvent Class but it is always returning the value 1.0, I think I am using it in a wrong way. Please if you can send me an example of the implementation.

Comment: the docs i sent in my first comment say: *"This value is a number ranging from 0.0, indicating a touch with no discernible pressure, to 1.0, indicating a touch with "normal" pressure, and possibly beyond, indicating a stronger touch. For devices that do not detect pressure (e.g. mice), returns 1.0."* - notice the last sentence

Comment: GestureDetector (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html )class has onForcePressUpdate and other methods using which you can measure force applied on the screen. I tested the flutter app on iphone and it worked fine but, when I tried to build a webapp and tested it on safari browser then it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please send an example for the implementation @RahulSahni

Comment: @AbedBaltaji Use GestureDetector as a widget like this.

GestureDetector(
              onForcePressUpdate: (ForcePressDetails details) {
                print("onForcePressUpdate: ${details.pressure}");
              },
              child: const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text(
                    'PRESS'
                ),

              ),
            )

Comment: @RahulSahni Which iPhone model did you used when it worked with you? Because I've read that there is specific models of iPhone that support pressure detection.

Comment: @AbedBaltaji iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 7, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone X, iPhone XS, and iPhone XS Max. Only these devices have force touch

Comment: @RahulSahni did find a solution for the forcePressDetection in a flutter webapp? Or you have any other suggestions.

Comment: @AbedBaltaji I ended up using React for my use-case because I couldn't figure it out